# How can I edit rows of table and table header manually in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I want to implement dynamic table of rows and columns.

User enter rows and columns and table is created, intially i have set the values to "Enter Text" and everything is working, now I want user can manually edit the table by clicking on the values on row or header cell.here's my below code:

```
 <table id="mytable"   className="table table-striped table-nowrap dataTable" cellSpacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                {this.state.colarray.map((coldata,ind)=>{
                                    return(
                                        <th>{coldata}</th>
                                        )
                                })}
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                             <tbody>
                             {console.log("rows",this.state.rowarray)}
                             {this.state.rowarray.map((rowdata,ind)=>{
                                 return(<tr>
                                     {this.state.colarray.map((col,index)=>{
                                         return(
                                                 <td>{rowdata['item'+index]}</td>
                                         )
                                     })}
                                 </tr>)

                             })}
                             </tbody>
                        </table>
```

How the user can change the array data mapped on table,by manually entering data in table cells and header.